# What is this Hilbert space?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

The space is $H^s(\mathbb R^d)$. If $f$ is in this space, it means

$\int_\mathbb {R^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^s|\hat f(\xi)|^2d\xi < \infty$

where $\hat f$ is the fourier transform of $f$: $\hat f(\xi)=\int_\mathbb {R^n} f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx$.

Any good properties for this space?

I found out that if s=1, than $f$, $\nabla f\in L^2$

if s=2, then $f,\nabla f, \Delta^2f\in L^2$.

My goal is to prove

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \hat f(\xi) e^{i(\xi,x)}d\xi$ where$(\xi, x)$ is the inner product=$x_1\xi_1 +x_2\xi_2...$

And I want to show that if $f\in H^s$,
$|f|_{L^\infty}\leq c|f|_{H^2}$

Comment: $H^s$ is a *Sobolev space*, and the statement you want to prove is the *Fourier inversion formula*.  Both of these will be discussed at length in most graduate real analysis textbooks.  Can you be more specific about what kind of "good properties" you want?

Comment: I have heard that Hilbert walked into Courant's office one day and asked: “What is this thing they call Hilbert space?”. I have no idea if the story is true, but the title of your question reminded me of it. Anyhow, the Laplace operator is usually written as $\Delta$ or $\nabla^2$. What you wrote, $\Delta^2$, would be the bi-Laplacian. You'd need to be in $H^4$ to ensure that $\Delta^2f\in L^2$.

Comment: But I thought the incersion formula is kind of different from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Sobolev space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SobolevSpace.html). These spaces have many nice properties! The link there (and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)) should get you going...